# Change data in repeater when date changes in .datepicker

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, datepicker

My problem is that I have a datepicker in a textbox. When I change date with the picker I want a repeater to change the data inside.

I have set the textbox to autopostback=true, but everytime the datepicker changes the date back to todays date.

I want to disable that function on the .datepicker.

Here are my datepicker:

```
<div class="input-group date" id="divChooseDateForReport">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtChooseDateForReport" CssClass="form-control disabled txtDatePicker" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $('.txtDatePicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    todayBtn: true,
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    weekStart: '1',
    goToCurrent: false,
    todayHighlight: true
 });

</script>
```

Comment: use `txtChooseDateForReport_TextChange` event and filter the data in `repeater` and bind it.

Comment: But the event doesnt fire in code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The place where you are assigning value to your date picker (probably in the page_load()) you have to surrond ti by :

```
if(IsPostBack == false)
{
   //code for initializing your date picker
}
```

Comment: That is already done but it will change the date to today even if I only set the date to today when page isnt postback

Comment: What if you remove  `todayHighligth : true` ?

Comment: @MrKrantz Wait.... i don't see where you make the link between your javascript and your asp control, neither why you put postback to true if you intend to make it a client side control ?

Comment: I want it to be server side... I dosent know how I calls a method in code behind (contains stored procedure) from client side

Comment: I have tested to remove todayHighlight but nothing been different

Comment: The problem was tha auto post. It should be false. Thanks!